# UWP server socket always listening

Tags: sockets, uwp, background-task, suspend

I implemented an UWP Server Socket following the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) and it correctly works.
Now I want to make the app able to continuously accept requests, but I expect that when the app is suspendeded and a client sends a request, the server is not able to respond. If I am correct, what is the best way to avoid this status change? If possible, I would prefer a solution with Extended Execution instead of implementing a Background Task, but I don't know if the following code in the OnSuspending method is enough to keep the app in the Running status:

```
var newSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
newSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
newSession.Revoked += SessionRevoked;
```

I saw people calling a "LongRunningWork()" function in other samples, but in my case the code to execute is already defined in the code-behind of the view as shown in the link above, so I would like simply keeping the app always running. Keep in mind that it is a LOB application, so I don't have Store limits.

Comment: Are you want to implement the function that Postpone your app suspension so that your socket can still connect? You can implement the extended execution following the document [Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) and the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution).

Comment: Yes and it worked, thanks!